# Highlight text in a box when tapped?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

How you have the text highlighted in a textbox when tapped?

this is my code:

```
    TextSelection.Equals(bar.Text);
```

Comment: I'm a little confused. Do you want the highlighted text or you want to highlight the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a little confused about your question since TextSelection relates to a RichTextBox. I would just use the [SelectAll Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.selectall%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) of the TextBox that you tapped.

```
private void bar_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    bar.SelectAll();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can choose how many characters to select and where to start selecting from. This will select the entire text (although  if you want to always select the entire text, you can use the `SelectAll` method mentioned in Mark Hall's answer.

```
bar.Focus(); 
bar.SelectionStart = 0;
bar.SelectionLength = bar.Text.Length;
```

The `Focus()` call is sometimes required, depending on how you're calling this. If, for example, you decide that you want to press a button to select the entire text, you need to set the focus.